# How to modify resource file with forloop and build with Gradle Task (Android Project)

Tags: android

**My Case**

Our Android project has a resource file located in res/config.xml, when we distribute, we need pack more than 40 packages with different channel_id which is set in config.xml.

**Product Flavor?**

It seems I can't modify resource values in `productFlavor` settings. I can only modify packageName and manifest etc, it can't modify resource files and can't do for loop.

**Task**

I am wandering if there is a way to write a TASK which can set channel_id and build in a for loop.